# openpyxl 1.8.6 module Excel Protection not applying

Tags: javascript, python, excel

I am using python openpyxl 1.8.6 module for reading and writing into Excel

I am using protection method from this module and trying to protect the cell in Excel by not writing into Excel,but its not working.

Here is my code...

```
from openpyxl.style import Protection 
wb = Workbook()
ws = wb.active
ws.cell('A8').style.protection.locked=Protection.PROTECTION_PROTECTED
```

Comment: I know that in Excel you have to switch on the protection for the whole workbook also in order to get the cell protections to work.

Comment: How to ON the protection?

Comment: Maybe in ws.protection you can set the various attributes to True

Comment: I used the below code but its not getting ptotected


ws.protection.sheet=True
ws.protection.objects=True
ws.cell('A8').style.protection.locked=Protection.PROTECTION_PROTECTED